# How to prevent creating a nested output directory in vite.js

Tags: javascript, rollup, vite

For my vite app, I'm looking to have multiple entry points. In this case, I moved my `index.html` into `src/main`. After building, I noticed that there are nested directories in my dist folder which is not what I wanted.

[image]

I've been reading the [rollup docs](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#makeabsoluteexternalsrelative) to find the correct option to prevent this but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find a solution with rollup or vite docs. However, once I placed my html files at the root of the directory, I found that they were bundled properly in my build.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem as you and after hours of searching this is how I solved it:

1. Create js file (build.js - or whatever name you want)
2. In this build.js file with some help from nodejs file system module(fs) you can modify structure of dist folder as you want.
3. Finally, modify package.json file to run build.js file after vite build command, for example: `"build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build --mode=production && node PATH_TO_YOUR_BUILD_JS_FILE"`

Comment: This will break relative imports between the files.